# Can `pyright` LSP navigate to different module?

Tags: python, neovim, pyright, python-language-server, nvim-lspconfig

Is `pyright` goto definition command supposed to jump into the different modules?

I import python class like this `from a.b.c import Foo`.

When my cursor is on `a = Foo()` and I call [`lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()`](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#Keybindings-and-completion) nvim jumps only to the top of the file but does not follow the definition into the other module.
Executing the same command on the top import moves nowhere.

I use the [following script](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/441#issuecomment-745461421) in my init.vim to set up the `root_dir`

```lua
local util = require("lspconfig/util")

lspconfig.pyright.setup({
  root_dir = function(fname)
    return util.root_pattern(".git", "setup.py",  "setup.cfg", "pyproject.toml", "requirements.txt")(fname) or
      util.path.dirname(fname)
  end
})
```

Comment: Short answer - yes it is, it's working on my machine. Did you try lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()? And do you have your root directory configured properly? Look here https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Comment: Yes, I have the root directory setup and I also added the declaration. I added an example to my question. How could I verify if the value is correct?

Comment: Thank you, I found it. In my `init.vim`  ```on_attach = on_attach``` property was not passed to `pyright` lsp config. I add the key bindings in the on_attach function.

Comment: Glad to hear that!